# Running an executable within a new window using Command::new("open") in Rust is not working on mac

Tags: macos, rust

I am writing a scheduling program in rust which is supposed to run through different jobs/tasks and execute them concurrently using a Round Robin approach. However, to get Rust to run multiple executables at once, I need the program to open each job in a new window. This is the code I am using to attempt this.

```
fn main() {
    let interrupt = time::Duration::from_millis(20);

    let jobs = fs::read_dir("jobs").unwrap()
        .map(|res| res.map(|e| e.path()))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, io::Error>>().unwrap();

    let mut processes:Vec<Child> = vec![];
    let mut child: Child;
    for job in &jobs {
        // create a new process in a paused state
        child = Command::new("open").arg("-n").arg(job).spawn().expect("Failed");  // This line here does not work
        pause_process(child.id());
        processes.push(child);
    };
    loop {
        for child in &processes {
            continue_process(child.id());
            thread::sleep(interrupt);
            pause_process(child.id());
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me the error of ""job" can't be opened because (null) is not allowed to open documents in Terminal." This is an error from my mac and not from rust itself.
Running this command ("open -n ") works when I run it directly in the terminal.

I have tried making executables of this code doing "cargo build --release" and enabling full disk access for both my job executable and my rust executable. Pretty much everything I do results in the same error.

Comment: This is a permissions problem, where applications that access certain user directories must be given explicit access. Is your Terminal authorized? Does this work with other directories specified?

Comment: I've given my terminal accessibility and full disk access in Privacy & Security. It does not work with other applications in other directories.

Comment: the first thing I'd try to get a clear picture of what's going on is temporarily replace the expect with unwrap, so you can see the actual error given. If you intend to use these in a production scenario, it's probably a good idea to use anyhow or thiserror instead for a more robust error handling